Programme is made unclosable when mathplotlib is integrated INSIDE OF tkinter
I am using matplotlib with tkinter and I wanted the graphic screen/canvas/plot to be inside of the tkinter window so I made the matplotlib window into a widget inside of tkinter:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()
label = tk.Label(window,text="test")
label.pack()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
def draw():
    ax.hist([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5],5)
    canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()


window.mainloop()

but now, when the window is closed, the python terminal keeps on running, making it impossible to close if there is no console tab opened. I have looked online about this issue and it is said I have to repeat plt.show() twice at the end to make matplotlib close but since I am not using plt.show() method to display the graphics, it is impossible to close. Please help me about this issue
